# Good sources for hand-drawn stock illustrations?

Tags: stock-images

I'm looking for suppliers of hand-drawn stock imagery for a project that needs a consistent visual language (hence there should be larger quantities of material from the same artist/s) but doesn't have enough of a budget to hire an actual illustrator to do custom-tailored work.

Do such specialized archives exist? The material provided by mainstream stock archives is hardly consistent enough, and tends to veer on the "vector illustration" side rather than a real "hand drawn" look.

Answer (score 4):

You might have better luck at a book store / Amazon than online for this. Or hiring an illustrator since you need a consistent visual language.

There are books dedicated to royalty free illustrations, mostly old ones that are no longer covered by copyrights: [Royalty Free Illustration Books](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Royalty%20Free%20illustrations)

For example there's an entire book [Animals: 1,419 Copyright-Free Illustrations of Mammals, Birds, Fish, Insects, etc (Dover Pictorial Archive)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486237664)

which as noted in the title has 1,419 illustrations along these lines:

[image]

Comment: How interesting I never even considered using books like this? So would you simply scan and use?

Comment: @DevlinTube that or go to archive dot org and find pre scanned versions of books in public domain.